# How to run a clang libtool?

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have downloaded LLVM and built it in a build folder. To add a new clang libtool called observer.cpp , I am going into the LLVM directory and inside tools/clang/tools i am creating a new folder with my example libtool and the a cmake file as follows:

```
set( LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  ${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD}
  Option
  Support
  )

add_clang_executable(observer
  observer.cpp
  )

target_link_libraries(observer
  clangAST
  clangBasic
  clangDriver
  clangFrontend
  clangRewriteFrontend
  clangStaticAnalyzerFrontend
  clangTooling
  )

install(TARGETS observer
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Then i add the line

`add_clang_subdirectory(example)` in the cmake file in tools/clang/tools

Then I am building llvm again from the updated llvm directory, but I do not see observer in my build/bin folder.

How do I add this libtool so that I can run it?